# REST http put call

Tags: c#, angularjs, rest, http, put

I am trying to make a `PUT` call to my service to update a `user`

I get 404 when code hits my URL but in dev tools if I click URL it fails at it actually hits my controller. I'm thinking I'm passing my model wrong as parameter, can someone please point to me proper direction please, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

here is my service call

```
var updateUser = function(user) {
        return $http({
            method: "PUT",
            url: serviceBase + "/UserController/PutUser",
            data: user
        }).success(successCallBack).error(errorCallBack);
    }
```

and here is my controller

```
[HttpPut]
    [Route("api/UserController/PutUser")]
    public IHttpActionResult PutUser(UserDto user)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

    }
```

I tried using `JSON.stringify(user)` in my `$http` call as well and was out of luck get same `404` error but after clicking actual link it will hit my controller

Thank you for your advise!

Comment: Because your url ends with `/{user}` which is a place holder.

Comment: @DannyChen
I updated my code with out  /{user} still have same issue

Answer (score 1):

While the common practice is to also include an identifier with PUT requests you can still achieve what you desire with some minor changes.

First update the URL for the intended endpoint in the controller.

NOTE: This is just an example. Modify to suit your specific needs.

```
public class UsersController : ApiController {

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("api/Users")]
    public IHttpActionResult Put(User user) {
        try {
            //assuming some form of storage for models
            repository.Users.Update(user);
            return Ok();
        } catch (Exception) {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

... and then update your service call...

```
var updateUser = function(user) {
    return $http({
        method: "PUT",
        url: serviceBase + "/api/Users",        
        data: user
    }).success(succesCallBAck).error(errorCallBack);
}
```

the `user` will be sent in the body of the request to the controller.

Comment: I get this in cosole - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). when i click on url it shows it give me this "{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}"
I was able to create POST and GET with no issues. I dont know why i cant understand PUT operation :/

Comment: This is not REST. Read the title of question again.

Comment: updated the controller action and js. same issue. i get 404 and when i go to url tells me "{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}"
I dont understand why its trying to use GET when im telling it to use PUT in my controller.

Comment: What do you mean by `when i go to url`? The error message, is it what you get in the callback?

Comment: In console window I get : failed to load resources. The server responded with 404. And it shows the URL I was trying to hit. If I go to that URL manually I get the requested resource does not support GET.

Comment: Right when you `go` to the URL manually you are attempting a GET. hence the error message.

Comment: is it possible i have to enable enable my handlers in web.config file? ?I just cant hit my service when i use PUT method.

Comment: Well the assumption was that they were already enabled. check that your `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-*` handlers have the relevant verbs allowed `verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE"`

Comment: @Nkosi Thank you for help. will try that and update with the result.

Comment: was able to use this code to make POST request. but get 404 when do PUT. any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the id of the user at the end of url. Your methods needs 2 parameters. One userId and one User.

You may also want to revise your url structure.

Comment: But what if want to pass my object into put method

Comment: You pass the object in the body, and pass the id in the url. So your method needs 2 parameters. Edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry might ne noob question.s o put dont take in object as single parameter?

Comment: Also can you please explain what u mean by revise URL structure. I'm jr developer and this tasks are new to me.

Comment: In a RESTful api, the url for editing a User can be like /api/Users/1, where 1 is the id of the user and combined with PUT, server knows it should update that user with data in request's body. I see words "Edit" and "Update" in the url which make me think you have the wrong structure for controllers and methods

Comment: Thank you for explanation. So in my js I should pass parameters property with I'd and data property with user object?

Comment: Your put method accepts a posted User model. The id is within that model. You should not require a separate id parameter. The route should simply be /api/users, method PUT, and the User model in the request body.

Comment: @S. Brentson, it depends on whether they want to follow REST or not.

Comment: @S. Brentson, not remotely but by carrying a "rest" tag. I felt responsible for letting them know that what they are doing needs some work to be REST.